# Md-chip-list is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have been trying to insert some md-chip elements in my project. All I get is "`md-chip-list` is not a known element".

`HTML`:

```html
<md-chip-list>
    <md-chip *ngFor="let dependency of externalDependencies" color="primary" class="chip">
        {{dependency.name}}
    </md-chip>
</md-chip-list>
```

I have imported MdChipsModule, as I have seen in other answers:

```ts
import { MdChipsModule } from '@angular/material';
```

The code works if I leave out the `md-chip-list` tag, but the format is not as expected. I am new to Angular Material, so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What version of `@angular/material` are you using?

Comment: Did you include the module in the `imports`

Comment: @Edric I did 'npm angular-material --v' and it says 5.0.4.

Comment: You were supposed to install `@angular/material` (for Angular 2/4), not `angular-material` (for AngularJS).

Comment: @Skeptor Now I did and it worked! That was the problem, many thanks and sorry for the noob question!

Comment: No problem, I was afraid to ask that question as it looked too obvious but sometimes these are the difficult things we miss :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was module not included in the `imports` .

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

In code

```
import { MdChipsModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [MdChipsModule],
  ...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6):

Add below code in module.

import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';

@NgModule({

...
imports: [MatChipsModule]
...
})